# Proving that $A \cap (A \cup B) = A$ . Please check solution

Tags: elementary-set-theory, proof-verification

For homework I need to prove the folloving:
$$
A \cap (A \cup B) = A
$$

I did that in the following manner:
$$
A \cap (A \cup B)\\
x \in A \land (x \in A \lor x \in B)\\
(x \in A\ \land x \in A) \lor (x \in A \land x \in B)\\
x \in A \lor (x \in A \land x \in B)\\
\text{now I have concluded that x belongs to A,}\\
\text{because of the boolean expression, because I get something like this:}\\
x \in A \lor (x \in A \land x \in B) = x \in A\\
\text{when $x \in A$ is true the whole expression will be true}\\
$$

Did I do it right???
thanks

Comment: I believe there is a typo in the first line: $A \cap B(A \cup B)$?  Do you mean $x \in A \cap (A \cup B)$?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, you are correct. The given equality can be expressed by the two implications:  $x \in A\cap (A \cup B) \implies x \in A$, and the implication $x \in A \implies x \in A \cap(A\cup B)$. Since both implications are satisfied, so is the set equality.

Just be careful in your "equations" (i.e., your use of the "equal sign here"). You wrote:

> $$x \in A \lor (x \in A \land x \in B) \underbrace{=}_{\uparrow ?} x \in A$$

It would be more correct to conclude: $$x \in A \lor (x \in A \land x \in B)\;\underbrace{\iff}_{\text{if and only if}}\; x \in A$$

from which it follows $$A \cap (A \cup B) = A$$

Comment: Nice and detailed. +1

Answer (score 1):

Or you can just think that $A\subset A\cup B$ and thus from the definition of $\cap$ you have that $A\cap (A\cup B)=A$

Answer (score 1):

In general, for *any* two sets $\;X,Y\;$ , we **always** have that

$$X\cap Y=X\iff X\subset Y$$

With the above your exercise is thus trivial...

Answer (score 1):

Using fundamental laws of Set Algebra

$$\begin{cases}A \cap (A \cup B) & Given\\
=(A \cap A) \cup (A \cap B) & \text{Distributive Law}\\
=A \cup (A \cap B) & A \cap A = A\\
=A & A \cap B \subset A
\end{cases}$$